# Attach a private function at a hook?

Tags: functions, private

I have a class with some private & public functions. The thing is that I don't want some of the functions to be able to be called outsite of the class, so I want to make them private. But I need to hook them at particular hooks and the hooks cannot call them if they are private. Is there some workaround for that?

Comment: Using an intermediary public function?

Answer (score 7):

No that's impossible. When *WordPress* calls a method it has to be public. You could write a public method that is called on the hook which calls a private method inside.
Not sure if that makes sense though …

Comment: I agree. Yeah as in my example above, you can, but does it really make sense? Well, although the content can't be modified nor the private method accessed you have to ask is that the best approach..

Answer (score 2):

Yet another slightly more brief way is now available using anonymous functions with fn() =>

```
<?php
class myAdminMenu{
    public function __construct(){
        add_action('admin_menu', fn() => $this->doStuff());
    }

    private function doStuff(){
        echo "<center><h1>hello world</h1></center>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example;

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', array( 'someClass', 'init' ));

class someClass {

    protected static $content = 'oh yeah, private!';    

    public static function init() {
        $class = __CLASS__;
        new $class;
    }

    private function __construct() {
        add_filter('the_content', array(&$this, 'get_this_function'));
    }

    public static function get_this_function(){
         return self::my_funk_she_on();
    }

    private static function my_funk_she_on(){
        return self::$content;
    }

}
```

In this example I am filtering `the_content` by passing a private function which gets its value from a private variable. Now since you can't call this directly my `get_this_function` is what will return what's private and that's what I pass into my constructor that adds the appropriate filter upon `template_redirect`.

You don't need to use static methods by the way, some recommend against it, but do as you please.

Comment: The function called on the hook is still public. And there is no way around it.

Comment: Yep, agreed. The only advantage is that you can't modify what the private method returns, nor can you access it directly, but you can `return` it. But again... is that the best approach? Would be good if user provides some context and code to see too...

Answer (score 0):

Generally hook performs outside of a class. It has been invoked inside a class or class method. So you cannot use it in a hook. If you do it by forcefully you shall have to instantiate inside a public method first, then use the public method into any hook.
Example:

```
<?php
class tlSmAdminMenu{
    public function __construct(){
        add_action('admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_menu_page'));
    }
    public function add_menu_page(){
        add_menu_page('Themelines Plugin', 'TL Social Monster', 'manage_options', 'tl_social_monster', array( $this, 'admin_menu_cb'), '
dashicons-networking', 110);
    }
    public function admin_menu_cb(){
        $this->doStaff();
    }
    private function doStaff(){
        echo "<center><h1>THEMELINES SOCIAL MONSTER</h1></center>";
    }
}
if(class_exists('tlSmAdminMenu')){
    $tl_sm_obj= new tlSmAdminMenu();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP 5.4 or higher, you can achieve this using a closure and [`bindTo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php) method:

```php
$cb = function(){
  $this->callPrivateMethod();
};

$cb->bindTo($this);

add_action('init', $cb);
```

The above code is executed *in the scope of a class* hence `$this` is a valid value.